# Gene manipulation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

1. I want to create the following freq columns for the below df/table (clean_df_mut_counts)
2. Get the 2nd highest frequency allele at each patient*gene

patient  gene A_count C_count G_count T_count   A_freq.  C_freq G_freq  C_freq

"ptp_1"   "BRCA1" values.  values values.  values

"ptp_1"   "BRCA2" values.

"ptp_2"   "BRCA1"

"ptp_2"   "BRCA2"

tried as below. was able to get the pivot_wider to work which gave result as below-

```
clean_df_mut_counts_wide <- clean_df_mut_counts %>%  pivot_wider(
  names_from = base,
  values_from = count
)
```

result of above code-

[image]

```
clean_df_mut_counts_wide %>% 
    group_by(A, T, C, G) %>% 
      summarise(n = n()) %>% 
        mutate(freq= n/sum(n)) %>%
            top_n(n=2)
```

result of above code-
[image]

Comment: [Please provide a reproducible example of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Please use ``dput()`` to share data and not as an image.

Comment: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/